# Is there a clever way using Math functions to handle pagination with rotation?

Tags: javascript, math

I guess everybody has had this scenario when implementing a pagination: You are on the first or last element and the user goes forth or back and starts a new rotation. My naive implementation is this:

```js
let total = 3;
let index = 0;

const goto = (where) => {
  index += where === 'prev' ? -1 : 1;

  if (index < 0) index = total - 1;
  if (index >= total) index = 0;
  
  document.getElementById('b').textContent = index;
}

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', () => goto('prev'));
document.getElementById('c').addEventListener('click', () => goto('next'));
```

```html
<button id="a" type="button">Prev</button>
<span id="b">0</span>
<button id="c" type="button">Next</button>
```

Is there a way to simplify these cumbersome if-clauses using some clever math? Also, is a possible alternative also easy to read and to follow for somebody else reading the code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the offsets of `prev` and `next` as variable and use the remainder to get a value between zero (with) and total (without).

```js
const
    prev = -1,
    next = 1,
    total = 3;

let index = 0;

const goto = (where) => {
    index += total + where; // prevent negative value
    index %= total;         // get interval

    document.getElementById('b').textContent = index;
};

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', () => goto(prev));
document.getElementById('c').addEventListener('click', () => goto(next));
```

```html
<button id="a" type="button">Prev</button>
<span id="b">0</span>
<button id="c" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's aweseome. So simple and still couldn't see it.